# SVG.js version 3.0.5 - Animate a rectangle to move along a specified path

Tags: javascript, svg.js

I have come across a working example of using SVG.js version 2.5.0 for moving a rectangle along a path in jsfiddle. I am trying to duplicate the same behavior but in SVG.js version 3.0.5 but keep getting back an error.

The jsfiddle resides at : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dotnetCarpenter/vceakozz/) and my attempt is at : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/symbologysvg/67yj4wrm/5/)

When the code is run in chrome i get the following error in the console :

```
sugar.js:125 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getPointAtLength' on 'SVGGeometryElement': The provided float value is non-finite.
    at Path.pointAt (sugar.js:125:32)
    at o.<anonymous> (svgjsVersion3.html:24:34)
    at o.value (Runner.js:430:38)
    at o.value (Runner.js:305:28)
    at n.value (Timeline.js:274:29)
    at _draw (Animator.js:86:17)
```

The complete html of the page that i am running is :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SVG.js</title>
        <style>
            html, body, #drawing{
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }      
        </style>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@svgdotjs/svg.js@3.0/dist/svg.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onload();">
        <div id="drawing"></div>
        <script>
            function onload() {
                var draw = SVG().addTo('#drawing').size(800, 800);
                var rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({fill: '#f06'});
                var path = draw.path("m 357.64532,453.84097 c 17.62007,8.02216 -2.12058,27.70935 -13.33334,29.28571 -30.3859,4.27185 -48.34602,-29.97426 -45.23807,-55.9524 5.5594,-46.46879 56.1311,-70.59787 98.57145,-61.19043 62.28294,13.8058 93.32728,82.57702 77.1428,141.19051 C 453.21679,585.29693 365.67122,623.42358 290.97859,600.26951 196.98554,571.13248 151.71003,464.56996 181.93108,373.84089 218.53281,263.95583 344.23687,211.49702 450.97875,248.84102 576.77037,292.84963 636.43303,437.76771 591.93099,560.50775 540.55162,702.21597 376.3736,769.09583 237.6452,717.41234 80.01319,658.68628 5.9069261,475.21736 64.788247,320.50751 130.84419,146.94643 333.62587,65.607117 504.31214,131.69819 693.80625,205.0718 782.38357,427.18225 709.07382,613.84113");
                var length = path.length();
                path.fill('none').stroke({width: 1, color: '#ccc'});
                
                rect.animate(8000, '<>').during(function(pos, morph, eased){
                    var p = path.pointAt(eased * length)
                    rect.center(p.x, p.y)
                }).loop(true, true)            
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

I followed the advice from Armali and made the corrections as per below that worked.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SVG.js</title>
        <style>
            html, body, #drawing{
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }      
        </style>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@svgdotjs/svg.js@3.0/dist/svg.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onload();">
        <div id="drawing"></div>
        <script>
            function onload() {
                var draw = SVG().addTo('#drawing').size(800, 800);
                var rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({fill: '#f06'});
                var path = draw.path("m 357.64532,453.84097 c 17.62007,8.02216 -2.12058,27.70935 -13.33334,29.28571 -30.3859,4.27185 -48.34602,-29.97426 -45.23807,-55.9524 5.5594,-46.46879 56.1311,-70.59787 98.57145,-61.19043 62.28294,13.8058 93.32728,82.57702 77.1428,141.19051 C 453.21679,585.29693 365.67122,623.42358 290.97859,600.26951 196.98554,571.13248 151.71003,464.56996 181.93108,373.84089 218.53281,263.95583 344.23687,211.49702 450.97875,248.84102 576.77037,292.84963 636.43303,437.76771 591.93099,560.50775 540.55162,702.21597 376.3736,769.09583 237.6452,717.41234 80.01319,658.68628 5.9069261,475.21736 64.788247,320.50751 130.84419,146.94643 333.62587,65.607117 504.31214,131.69819 693.80625,205.0718 782.38357,427.18225 709.07382,613.84113");
                var length = path.length();
                console.log(length);
                path.fill('none').stroke({width: 1, color: '#ccc'});

                rect.animate(5000,1000).ease('<>').during(function(eased){
                    var p = path.pointAt(eased * length);
                    rect.center(p.x, p.y);
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is answered, i cant find the green tick to say it is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the advice and it works :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SVG.js</title>
        <style>
            html, body, #drawing{
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }      
        </style>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@svgdotjs/svg.js@3.0/dist/svg.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onload();">
        <div id="drawing"></div>
        <script>
            function onload() {
                var draw = SVG().addTo('#drawing').size(800, 800);
                var rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({fill: '#f06'});
                var path = draw.path("m 357.64532,453.84097 c 17.62007,8.02216 -2.12058,27.70935 -13.33334,29.28571 -30.3859,4.27185 -48.34602,-29.97426 -45.23807,-55.9524 5.5594,-46.46879 56.1311,-70.59787 98.57145,-61.19043 62.28294,13.8058 93.32728,82.57702 77.1428,141.19051 C 453.21679,585.29693 365.67122,623.42358 290.97859,600.26951 196.98554,571.13248 151.71003,464.56996 181.93108,373.84089 218.53281,263.95583 344.23687,211.49702 450.97875,248.84102 576.77037,292.84963 636.43303,437.76771 591.93099,560.50775 540.55162,702.21597 376.3736,769.09583 237.6452,717.41234 80.01319,658.68628 5.9069261,475.21736 64.788247,320.50751 130.84419,146.94643 333.62587,65.607117 504.31214,131.69819 693.80625,205.0718 782.38357,427.18225 709.07382,613.84113");
                var length = path.length();
                console.log(length);
                path.fill('none').stroke({width: 1, color: '#ccc'});

                rect.animate(5000,1000).ease('<>').during(function(eased){
                    var p = path.pointAt(eased * length);
                    rect.center(p.x, p.y);
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, while [SVG.js v2](https://svgjs.dev/docs/2.7/animating/#animate) says

> The `animate()` method will take three arguments. The first is `duration`, the second `ease` and the third `delay`…

[SVG.js v3](https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.0/animating/#animate) says

> The `animate()` method will take three arguments. The first is `duration`, the second `delay` and the third `when`…

So we have to change `animate(8000, '<>')` to `animate(8000).ease('<>')`.

Second, while [SVG.js v2](https://svgjs.dev/docs/2.7/animating/#callbacks) has an example with `…during(function(pos, morph, eased, situation) {…`, SVG.js v3 has no such example, and surprisingly passes only one parameter. It works if we change to just `…during(function(eased) {…`.